# Code Repo/Wiki for Academic Research Cluster?

Tags: version-control, wiki, mediawiki, archive, knowledge-management

(Not sure if this is the best SE, but nothing else seemed close enough)

I'm a 'fresh' PhD Researcher, and after chatting with most of my cluster-colleagues (including staff), I suggested putting together a system for sharing 'acquired experiential knowledge' (Digital Communications within Electrical Engineering, so lots of code, lots of languages, and lots of algorithms, therefore a lot of things to 'work out' twice.)

Any time that I've done major coding projects, it's been a single repository containing a single project, and this seems to be the general state of 'HOWTO' articles in this area. I'd be looking to put something together that would have a wiki 'front end' (I've got experience with Mediawiki so I will probably stick with that), with 'context' info and theoretical stuff, with a VCS 'backend' that would hold archives of code-bases that people wanted to share. The reasoning for this archive is that there is a lot of person-turnover and any generated code can disappear into the ether on their departure, so that experience is lost.

**Can anyone recommend any tools for this kind of multi-project VCS backend?** Ideally I'd like something similar to bitbucket but locally served.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a problem, which could be solved by using [github](http://www.github.com) or [bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org). Both offer (distributed) VCS with a wiki and an issue tracker. Github using Git and bitbasket using Mercurial. You can even make everything private.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it open, code.google.com is a possible solution

Comment: You following me Kurru :P 

Has to be 'closed open' i.e open within the research network.

Answer (score 0):

For self-hosting Git repositories, and fronting them with something like Gitweb, Gitolite is the current standard. Your wiki can then provide links to both gitweb and the actual repository URLs. Keep to the 'one repository per project' structure. Any cross-referencing (say by language, topic, and task) can happen in the wiki.